# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter - refresh, update DB

Tags: android, cursor, android-alertdialog, simplecursoradapter, android-context

My issue today is related to a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` I've implemented. Here are my activities `onCreate()` and the custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = customSharedPreference.edit();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
    op = new OperationsClass(getApplicationContext());
    op.open();

    Cursor cursor = op.getList();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] columns = new String[] { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.entry_aaa,R.id.entry_bbb, R.id.entry_ccc};

    MyCursorAdapter mAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_entry, cursor, columns, to);

    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    op.close();
}
```

`OperationsClass` manages a database and the `getList(`) function returns a cursor of the entries.

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        private Context context;
        private MyCursorAdapter here = this;

        private int layout;

        public MyCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            this.context = context;
            this.layout = layout;
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(final Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            Cursor c = getCursor();

            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

            int col1 = c.getColumnIndex("aaa");
            String name1 = c.getString(col1 );
            int col2 = c.getColumnIndex("bbb");
            String name2 = c.getString(col2 );
            int col3 = c.getColumnIndex("ccc");
            int name3 = c.getInt(col3 );

            final TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.entry_aaa);
            final TextView text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.entry_bbb);
            final TextView text3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.entry_ccc);

            text1.setText(name);
            text2.setText(name2);

            if (name3 == 0)
                text3.setText("Not checked");
            else {
                text3.setText("Checked");
                text3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                        text3.setText("Not checked");
                            // Here I would like to update my DB using
                            // OperationsClass and the SharedPrefs,
                            // and refresh the ListView with the new
                            // text value.
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View v, final Context context, Cursor c) {
            // Same operations as higher
        }
}
```

Basically what I want to achieve is to refresh the `ListView` when the users clicks on the third column, which means its value changes (has been clicked or has not been). In the same time I wish to update the DB and the `SharedPreferences`(I could create a new object of both classes and recover from the application context, but that seems pretty heavy).

---

I also wish to know if there is a way to trigger one of the implemented methods in one activity when an `AlertDialog` has been opened (in the same app, I actually want to add an element to my database through an `AlertDialog` and make the Activity that popped it up retrieve a new cursor and refresh its List).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically what I want to achieve is to refresh the ListView when the
>   users clicks on the 3rd column, which means its value changes (has
>   been clicked or has not been). In the same time I wish to update the
>   DB and the SharedPrefereces (I could create a new object of both
>   classes and recover from the application context, but that seems
>   pretty heavy).

First of all, you shouldn't be implementing that logic in the `newView` method because that method will not be called for every row due to the recycling. The `newView` should be used only to build a new row view and nothing more. Use the `bindView` method for any row logic.

Regarding the code in the `onClick` method I don't see where do you have problems. Update the database based on your logic and then query again the database for a `Cursor` with the new data and then use `swapCursor()` to update the adapter with the new values. This should work but it's not the recommended way mainly because you're doing every database operation on the main UI thread. Don't use the  `startManagingCursor` method because this method runs the queries on the main UI thread, instead have a look at implementing a [`Loader`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) in your activity to load data off the main UI thread. With a `Loader` you'll update the database values and then simply restart the `Loader` to update the list.

> I also wish to know if there is a way to trigger one of the
>   implemented methods in one activity when an AlertDialog has been
>   opened (in the same app, I actually want to add an element to my
>   database through an AlertDialog and make the Activity that poped it up
>   retrieve a new cursor and refresh its List).

You're not saying anything about how you show that `AlertDialog`. If you want to update the list after you add the new element then use the listeners for the `AlertDialog`'s buttons and the same code as above.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding the Loader and why I shouldn't use the newView this way. I'll look into it right away. When it comes to reloading the Cursor, my problem here is that the SimpleCursorAdapter class does know it needs a reload, but my main Activity within which it is displayed doesn't. So how would the Activity know it needs to query the database again ?

Comment: For the AlertDialog, I was focused on trying to interact with the Activity's lifecycle for no good reason. I'll build the ListAdapter on its Listener and invoke swapCursor() method. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterGriffin Why does the `Activity` have to know about the need to reload? Do you use other views in the UI that need the `Cursor`'s data?

Comment: The app i'm making is targeted for Android Gingerbread. Which means no Loader (comes with Honeycomb) and Cursor manipulation (such as startManagingCursor() is inherited from the Activity class, so I feel kinda trapped there :/

Comment: @PeterGriffin Loaders are available through the compatibility package to as below as 1.6 if I'm not mistaken. Check http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Answer (score 2):

**"Basically what I want to achieve is"**

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // if (the id of selected view matches what you want) {
    boolean checked;
    if (text3.getText().toString() == "checked") {
        boolean checked = true;
    } else {
        boolean checked = false;
    }
    op.updateRead(id, checked);     
    refreshCursorAdapter();
    setSharedPrefs();
    // }
```

**"to refresh the ListView when the users clicks on the 3rd column, which means its value changes (has been clicked or has not been)."**

```
private void refreshCursorAdapter() {
    Cursor cursor = op.getList();
    mAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
}
```

**"In the same time I wish to update the DB"**

```
private boolean updateRead(long rowId, boolean checked) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        if (checked) { 
            args.put("read", "1"); 
        } else { 
            args.put("read", "0");  
        }
        return db.update(DB_TABLE, args, "_id =" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
```

**"and the SharedPrefereces"**

```
private void setSharedPrefs() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    if (checked) { 
        editor.putBoolean("read", false);
    } else { 
        editor.putBoolean("read", true);
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

**"I also wish to know if there is a way to trigger one of the implemented methods in one activity when an AlertDialog has been opened"**

Quite honestly i don't understand what the mystique behind this one is. The process would involve copying and pasting the same code else to some other event.

Comment: You may want to use the `equals` method to compare `Strings`.